# Worklight 6.2 - hides LibInclude directory under iphone/native

Tags: iphone, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, xtify

On Worklight 6.2, if I create a directory anywhere under iphone/native called LibInclude, Worklight hides that directory and any contents in the Project Explorer view.  It will show up in the Pending Changes view if you use Jazz SCM, but when you try to check in any files, it will give an error about not being able to find the file.  If I create LibInclude anywhere NOT under iphone/native, it works normally.

This is an issue because Xtify uses a folder with this name for some files in it's SDK, and we can't check the files into SCM.

To recreate, create a WL project with an iPhone environment.  Then in your OS browser, navigate to iphone/native and create a folder called LibInclude.  Go back to eclipse and refresh from the Project Explorer view, and the folder you created will not be visible.

This works correctly in WL 6.1.

If there's any more info I can provide, please let me know.

Comment: "Then in your OS browser, navigate to iphone/native and create a folder called LibInclude" -- what does that mean? how can you create a folder from the browser?

Comment: Sorry for the poor terminology-- I meant Finder on Mac or Windows Explorer on Windows.  Or you can create from the CLI, too.

Comment: Looks like Eclipse allows to create this LibInclude folder with no issues in 6.1, but not so easily in 6.2... there is no much that can be done in Stack Overflow here. My suggestion is to remove this question and instead open it as a PMR.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that in 6.1 you can create this folder and in 6.2 you "can't", I do not understand the reason to do this to begin with.

You shouldn't need to create this folder because you can see that the LibInclude folder already exists in the application's folder structure: iphone\native\XtifyLib\CustomInbox\LibInclude.

Are you perhaps trying to add additional files to this folder for later use?
The scenario is not clear enough.

IF what you want is to add there files for later use, then also note that it is not enough to just place files there, because after building and opening the Xcode project, those files will not be linked - you will still need to select "Add files..." (in Xcode) and add the files so that they will be known to the project.

Additionally, you may want to store your additional files(?) not in the iphone\native folder, but in the iphone\nativeResources folder.
Simply recreate the folder structure within: iphone\nativeResources\XtifyLib\CustomInbox\LibInclude

Then you can save in your SCM the nativeResources folder instead of the native folder.
On the next build, the files from the nativeResources folder will be copied into the native folder respectively.

Note that you will still need to link the files when the project is later opened in Xcode.

---

It will help if you will explain the full scenario